# Can we connect initiator to alternate FIX acceptor if existing acceptor failed?

Tags: java, .net, quickfix

I have one FIX initiator running on my machine and two FIX acceptor 'A' and 'B' are running on different machine. If suppose 'A ' fails to respond then I want to connect automatically to acceptor 'B'.
Is it possible to configure either FIX initiator or acceptor?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it. [It is mentioned in the config section of Quickfix/J](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.0/usage/configuration.html)

This is the entriy you need to do for the initiator for failing over to another host. Put that in your initiator config file.

> SocketConnectHost   Alternate socket hosts for connecting to a session for failover, where n is a positive integer. (i.e.) SocketConnectHost1, SocketConnectHost2... must be consecutive and have a matching SocketConnectPort[n]

Comment: Yes I gone through it. It worked fine.Thank you for the same. So now another problem I faced that we can not keep track on message logs saved on which are at now different machine respective to acceptors 'A', 'B'...so on. Now I am working to keep it on shared folder but initiator fails to log in as session message log files denied to edit while another acceptor is running using same files.